# <core-shared-lib> and load event in polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to use a js library across my elements with the help of `core-shared-lib` element. Apparently, I need to perform an operation as soon as the library loads, and the Polymer's ready event gets fired before the library is downloaded. Is there a way that I can bind an event to core-shared-lib element so that I can execute that library's functions.

Thank You

Comment: Also look how Google web components do this on their github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `on-core-shared-lib-load` event according to [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-shared-lib.html). Try that

```
<core-shared-lib on-core-shared-lib-load="{{load}}" url="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js?onload=%%callback%%">
```